# GPO to set firefox proxy

Tags: proxy, group-policy, firefox

**CONTEXT**

- I have recently assigned to restructure a corporate network that contains about 100 client computers.
- There is an active directory domain (2003 functional level) for the whole network.
- The user uses two browsers: IE and Firefox

I have to switch from normal proxy (configured on each machine) to transparent proxy so i have to remove proxy settings from IE and Firefox (I have already implemented the GPO for IE with no problem)

**PROBLEM**

I want to use GPO or similar to disable proxy in firefox, i looked up on google but with no luck

**OPPORTUNITY**

The company is located in a single site so the amministrative effort to implement the solution must be less than change directly the settings on each computer.

*Thank you in advance*

Answer (score 1):

[FirefoxADM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firefoxadm/) is a custom ADM template for controlling Firefox through Group Policy.

[Here](http://www.petri.co.il/adding_new_administrative_templates_to_gpo.htm) is an instruction for adding templates to GPOs.

[Here](http://support.kaspersky.com/us/faq/?qid=208281905) is a howto specific to FirefoxADM.

Answer (score 0):

[MozillaGPO project](https://mozillagpo.sourceforge.io/) provides mozilla [autoconfig.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MCD,_Mission_Control_Desktop_AKA_AutoConfig) module that allow managing mozilla software wia Group Policy.

It has advantages over FirefoxADM:

- module update preferences from policy every hour (and not only when the user logs on).
- there is no problem when Firefox is running before the configuration script
- suitable for Thunderbird too.